# Inno setup how to check if a string contains at least one special character

Tags: inno-setup

I am writing script to check if my password string contains at least one special character in it. I learned regex is not possible with InnoSetup.

Could someone help me in achieving this?

Thanks in Advance,

DeeJay

Comment: What is the *special character* ? Is it a char from some constant set that you want to declare ?

Comment: And you can use regex in Inno Setup. Either from some external library, or e.g. use the `VBScript.RegExp` Windows automation object. But for what you described sounds regex a bit heavy.

Comment: @TLama, thanks for the info...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```pascal
[code]
function PasswordContainsAtLeastOneSpecialChar(Pass : String) : Boolean;
var
    i : integer;
begin
    Result := false;

    for i:=1 to length(Pass) do
    begin
        case Pass[i] of
          '!', '"', '§', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')', '=', '?', '\', '*', '#': // list all special characters here 
          begin
            Result := true;
            Exit;
          end;
        end;
    end;                           
end;
```